# Clickable label in Amcharts5 Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts, amcharts5

I am trying to add to the Stacked Bar Chart the ability to click on the labels on the left side of the chart, but without effectiveness.
There are some posts on the Internet on how to add links to labels, but they are for Amcharts4 and don't work on Amcharts5.

I have a chart like this: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-bar-chart/
and I would like the labels "2021", "2022" and "2023" on the left to be clickable (with any links).

Attempting to do this with the renderer failed (maybe I did it on the wrong element), inserting HTML in the label causes the HTML code to be displayed, not interpreted on the link.

Below is the code from the website:

```js
import am4themes_https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/Animated";

/* Chart code */
// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
let chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
  panX: false,
  panY: false,
  wheelX: "panY",
  wheelY: "zoomY",
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));

// Add scrollbar
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/scrollbars/
chart.set("scrollbarY", am5.Scrollbar.new(root, {
  orientation: "vertical"
}));

let data = [{
  "year": "2021",
  "europe": 2.5,
  "namerica": 2.5,
  "asia": 2.1,
  "lamerica": 1,
  "meast": 0.8,
  "africa": 0.4
}, {
  "year": "2022",
  "europe": 2.6,
  "namerica": 2.7,
  "asia": 2.2,
  "lamerica": 0.5,
  "meast": 0.4,
  "africa": 0.3
}, {
  "year": "2023",
  "europe": 2.8,
  "namerica": 2.9,
  "asia": 2.4,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.9,
  "africa": 0.5
}]

// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
  categoryField: "year",
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
}));

yAxis.data.setAll(data);

let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  min: 0,
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
}));


// Add legend
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
let legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
  centerX: am5.p50,
  x: am5.p50
}));

// Add series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
function makeSeries(name, fieldName) {
  let series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
    name: name,
    stacked: true,
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    baseAxis: yAxis,
    valueXField: fieldName,
    categoryYField: "year"
  }));

  series.columns.template.setAll({
    tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryY}: {valueX}",
    tooltipY: am5.percent(90)
  });
  series.data.setAll(data);

  // Make stuff animate on load
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
  series.appear();

  series.bullets.push(function () {
    return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
      sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
        text: "{valueX}",
        fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
        centerY: am5.p50,
        centerX: am5.p50,
        populateText: true
      })
    });
  });

  legend.data.push(series);
}

makeSeries("Europe", "europe");
makeSeries("North America", "namerica");
makeSeries("Asia", "asia");
makeSeries("Latin America", "lamerica");
makeSeries("Middle East", "meast");
makeSeries("Africa", "africa");

// Make stuff animate on load
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
chart.appear(1000, 100);
```

I will appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/labels/#labels-as-interactive-elements). If we want to make label interactivity we need to add a background to it.

> The background does not necessarily have to be visible: we can just
> set its fillOpacity: 0 to make it completely transparent.

**Try this:**

```
yAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.setup = function(target) {
  target.set("background", am5.Rectangle.new(root, {
    fill: am5.color(0xff0000),
     fillOpacity: 0
  }))
}

yAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.events.on("click", function(ev) {
  console.log("Label", ev.target);
});
```

**[Working Example](https://codepen.io/chellappanrajan/pen/NWXXpmp)**

Answer (score 0):

I have previously just created my own click event whilst preventing any defaults that may happen with the chart. You can add click events to AM charts after you have instantiated it, then you can just make your click open a modal or toolitp or something, you can use CSS to position it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I know, I can add click event to some chart elements. I already added click event to data, but I didn't found a possibility to add click event to this label I want.
`function handleColumnClick(ev: any) { window.location = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.url; }; series.columns.template.events.on('click', handleColumnClick);`

Comment: Have you tried this mate:

`series.labels.template.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
  alert('clicked on ' + ev.target.dataItem.category + ' with a value of ' + ev.target.dataItem.value);
});`

Comment: Yes, I have tried this before, and get error that the element "labels" doesn't exist on ColumnSeries, even though it exists in FunnelSeries :/
I also tried this `yAxis.get('renderer').labels.template.events.on('click', function (ev) {console.info('clicked');});`, but nothing happens on click.